# why is there cos $\theta$ in the elemental law of induction?

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

I am reading Peter Graneau's "[Newtonian Electrodynamics](https://archive.org/stream/NewtonianElectrodynamics/Newtonian%20Electrodynamics#page/n29/mode/2up)" in which he discusses electromagnetic induction between two current element as follows:

[image]

[image]

What I don't understand is the insertion of cos $\theta$ in the formula. By what **experimental evidence** or **theoretical reasons** Neumann inserted cos $\theta$ in the elemental law of induction? Can anybody explain it? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Continue further until eq ($1.40$). It shows that:
$$\mathrm{v_x\cos{\theta_{x,r}} = \frac{dr}{dt}}$$
The $\cos$ is here to make a projection on the vector joining the two points.

Comment: What **experimental evidence** or **theoretical reasons** tell us that induced emf is proportional to the projection of velocity on the vector joining the two points. I can't see about it anywhere in the book.

Comment: The experimental evidence possibly comes later in the book?

Comment: @Farcher: Please can you tell where? It's not in the page from where you have taken the image.